やっぱり used as a noun here?
Bakemonogatari episode 1, two students are discussing how it is strange that a third student who's otherwise a good student hasn't been coming, and one of the students says that she doesn't really know her:

でも同じクラスになってまだちょうど １ か月くらいだしね
分かんないってのがやっぱりかな
ゴールデンウイーク挟んじゃってるし
But I've only been in the same
class as her for a month.
Indeed, I don't know her that well.
Golden Week lies within that month.

I thought these kinds of sentences I used to struggle with I was beginning to understand but well...
What is weird to me is how I feel this is an abbreviation for 。。。やっぱりだ, which isn't natural like 当然だ.
Right now I break it down like:

"The very fact that I don't know I guess is all the same/as before/as expected"

...but my use of "is" implies that やっぱり is being used like a noun which doesn't work.
Is it more an abbreviation of something like やっぱりそうかな or やっぱり本当かな?

Like you said, ～がやっぱりだ is not a common use of やっぱり, but I think this is acceptable as a colloquial sentence. やっぱり(か/だ) said on its own usually means "I knew it!" or "As expected!", so やっぱりだ in your sentence can be understood along these lines; it expresses the mood that the result does not exceed one's expectation.

分かんないってのがやっぱりかな。

I'm not sure — is what can be expected, I guess.
So it's "I don't know", as you may expect.
"I don't know" is all I know for now.


